# Рисование точки по нажатию кнопки мыши с помощью PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, рисование

У меня есть поле `QPainter`, как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки мыши, рисовалась точка в позиции курсора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой вариант рисования:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Paint point example')

        self.point = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.point = event.pos()

        # Вызов перерисовки виджета
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.point = None

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        # Если нет
        if not self.point:
            return

        # Рисовать будем на самом себе
        painter = QPainter(self)

        # Для рисования точки хватит setPen, но для других фигур (типо rect) понадобится setBrush
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 20.0))

        # Рисование точки
        painter.drawPoint(self.point)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Вот так выглядит виджет после клика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

- Если нужно сохранять результат рисования, как на холсте, тогда рисовать фигуры нужно на `QImage` (или `QPixmap`), а в `paintEvent` рисовать на виджете ту картинку.
- Если нужно при движении мышки рисовать – использовать метод `mouseMoveEvent`
- Прикладываю [пример рисовалки](https://github.com/gil9red/fake-painter) на питоне. Больше [своих примеров рисования](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=user%3Agil9red%20%22def%20paintEvent%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) python + Qt

Comment: ещё [практически идентичный вариант](https://gist.github.com/zed/d1b63f81896e091b30b2f83e3ec6c1f1)

Answer (score 0):

Не так хорошо знаю PyQt, Но в обычном Qt это делается таким образом, надеюсь переписать проблемы не возникнет:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    point=e->pos();
    update();
}
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen linepen(Qt::red);
    linepen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
    linepen.setWidth(30);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);
    painter.setPen(linepen);
    painter.drawPoint(point);
}
```